# how to get just success message in firebase cloud message array in flutter

Tags: php, flutter

I implement FCM to send a push notification with PHP which works well but I will like to know if there is a way I can get just the `"success":1` from below

`{ "multicast_id": 72************, "success": 1, "failure": 0, "canonical_ids": 0, "results": [ { "message_id": "0:161*************" } ] }`

Using flutter POST or is there a way I can just let it return just a string saying success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You Can store your data in a `Map` Variable and then use the `containsKey` method of that `map` variable to assure that the "`success`" `key` exists or not. And if it does exists then `print` it using the below `code`.*

```
Map m =   { "multicast_id": "72************", "success": 1, "failure": 0, "canonical_ids": 0, "results": [ { "message_id": "0:161*************" } ] };
  print(m.containsKey("success"));
  print(m['success']);
```